# How to restrict access to phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, security, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to secure phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin)

I use phpmyadmin to preview the database of my website. However, everyone can access the login page of my phpmyadmin by simply typing `example.com/phpmyadmin`

I am not an expert in network security but I assume this isn't very secure.

How can I restrict the access to the login page(maybe creating some alias like `example.com/a4ebb72d` ).
I heard about allowing access only for specified IPs, but it won't help because I have dynamically assigned IP.

I'd be thankful for your tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin

Comment: Change the name from /phpmyadmin to something else, bots and vuln scanners look for that directory.   You should additional layers of security as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd make that server listen on `127.0.0.1` and then use port forwarding with SSH...

Make sure, the server serving phpMyAdmin only serves to 127.0.0.1, and then run

```
$ ssh -L4545:localhost:80 yourserver.com
```

and then point your browser to http://127.0.0.1:4545/phpmyadmin, you should be able to access phpmyadmin as long as your SSH session is active. You can even make a shell script to automate this.

This works with PuTTY as well.

Comment: Thanks that looks nice, I'll try it. But wouldn't that tunneling cause slow page loading?

Comment: I had great results using this kind of tunneling. In fact, I use that for all kind of proxy work.

Comment: @polemon Could you please tell me that how can I make `phpMyAdmin` to serve 127.0.0.1, I'm newbie :-).

Comment: @NullPointer There's many ways. You can start a dedicated webserver instance, but you can also configure your web server to serve the phpmyadmin directory only to localhost.

Answer (score 20):

Exposing any part of phpMyAdmin is a potential risk. You could use Apache's Allow/Deny directives:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 12.34.56.78
```

Replace `12.34.56.78` with your IP address, and put this in a .htaccess file in your phpMyAdmin folder.

Comment: This would be a great answer if the OP hadn't specifically said that IP restriction wasn't of use to him.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you can change the name of the directory to be something that is not easily guessable.

You can also place the directory (or a parent directory, if you can't do it in the `phpmyadmin` directory directly) under password protection [using `.htaccess`](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/). Regardless of this perceived enhanced security, it's probably not going to be much more secure. After all, phpMyAdmin requires a login and a password just as much as `.htaccess` would, so if you use weak passwords or password practices, you're still just as vulnerable, so obviously make sure that both user/password combinations are both unique and strong.

The best thing you can do is ensure that all your phpMyAdmin users/passwords are secure and that you only entrust them to people you trust. Keep in mind that phpMyAdmin allows for the dropping of tables and entire databases, so keep regular backups and continually ensure the integrity of the data on your server, because in reality hiding the directory name or placing it behind another login barrier is only worthwhile if your password practices are as secure as possible to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could install phpMyAdmin in a directory behind a firewall so that only users with inside access could get to it.