# WAMP - How to restrict access to phpMyAdmin for a dedicate ip address?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, ip-address, restrict

Maybe duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687940/how-to-restrict-access-to-phpmyadmin) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin)
but I didnt get my answer there. I want to restrict access to dedicate ip addresses (like 192.168.120.138)

I newly installed wamp server 2.0c (apache 2.2.8 & php 5.2.6 & phpmyadmin 2.11.6)
It keeps on saying

> **Forbidden**
>   You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

when I try to load "localhost/phpmyadmin"

this is my http.conf

```
Include "c:/wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf"
Include "c:/wamp/alias/*"
```

and this is my phpmyadmin.conf

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin2.11.6">
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 192.168.120.138
</Directory>
```

But I still see the forbidden msg. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart your wamp server, all services for the changes to take effect.

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin2.11.6">
    AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 192.168.120
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your phpmyadmin.conf temporarily to Allow All, can you get in? Don't forget to **restart Apache** after you make changes to these files to see the results.