# What should I do to protect user information as non-company?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I am just a developer who is personally developing some websites (on a donation basis) on a cheap (but good) standard web hosting. I'm also taking Computer Science on university, so definitely I do care about security for example.

So I have a website where users can create accounts and they are stored in the database, and I want it to be as secure **as possible** without spending money on security. The server is just running PHP and a MySQL database on an Apache web server.

**The practices I know I am able to do:**

- Use complex database usernames and passwords.
- Store the password in combination with a hashing algorithm (preferably **not** MD5) and a salt.
- Also not unimportant, use complex FTP usernames and passwords.

**Possibly flaws I know exist:**

- The database is 'accessible' via the internet, namely `www.host.tld/phpMyAdmin`, it still wants the username and password as input though. I do have access to `.htaccess` files.
- If someone hacks the database, they can get valuable information, namely email addresses.

**What else is there more that I can do, to do the best I can?**

Comment: A very good resource is Troy Hunts [Hack Yourself First](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/hack-yourself-first-how-to-go-on.html).

Comment: Just reading Hack Yourself First and it's really interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For PHPMyAdmin**

1. Change the default admin user
2. Lock the access page to PHPMyAdmin using .htaccess
3. Do not call the folder PHPMyAdmin
4. Use virtual directory settings in Apache to prevent browsing of directories, or have dummy index.php in all folders

**MySQL Security**

For MySQL security, create a new database user with the minimal security rights for your application to work - in cases when your PHP scripts are comprised, the damage can be contained.

**PHP**

Cross site scripting and MySQL injection are still common issues too - there are various PHP libraries (free!) which helps to sanitize input.

If you do allow user's uploads, set the permissions for those folders to 755, and ensure PHP can read such folders - some web hosts insist folders to have permission 777 before PHP can write to them. Avoid such hosts at all costs.

If you really wish to go an extra mile, you can encrypt sensitive information as a deterrent, though the attacker probably has all the time in the world to crack those info.

Consider using PHP frameworks that would have done the legwork for basic security, such as sanitizing of POST, GET and etc.

Comment: I just realized my web host is configured interestingly though. The direct database access (port 3306) is properly configured, initially only allowing `localhost`, but then they initially do allow anyone to connect to `hostname.tld/phpMyAdmin`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is a very bad practice to expose your PHPMyadmin login page to everyone over the internet. As per my knowledge, PHPmyadmin does not provide any mechanism to prevent Brute Force attacks. A Brute Force attack, in very simple words, is an attack in which the attacker tries to guess the password to your database. And however you salt your password, someone may get through it.

I suggest that you immediately restrict access to your database so that only authorized users have access to it. You can easily do this by tampering some config files. This answer might help you. 
[How to restrict access to phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687940/how-to-restrict-access-to-phpmyadmin)

Lets hope your DB stays protected from malicious attacks :)