# Restrict phpmyadmin access in the application itself

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

I would like to restrict the phpmyadmin access only to certain IP addresses. I cannot change the server configuration and I'm not in a position right now to change my httpd conf files. Is there a way to accomplish this in application level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that this is a duplicate of this:
[How to restrict access to phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687940/how-to-restrict-access-to-phpmyadmin)

But since my answer hasn't been given there yet here's what I think:

I've found that a way to accomplish this is to get into phpmyadmin's config.inc.php. You can find that in the root directory of the phpmyadmin directory.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = 'deny,allow';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = array(
   'deny % from all', 

   'allow % from 127.0.0.1', 
   'allow % from ::1',
   'allow % from *YOUR_IP_ADDRESS_HERE*',
);
```

Edit: If you're behind a proxy, which I think most production servers are. You should also set the trusted proxies for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR like so:

```
$cfg['TrustedProxies'] = array('*PROXY_IP_HERE*' => 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',);
```

Comment: Worked great. Helped me out there. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Please note that it is not possible to put ip ranges or cidr's in the TrustedProxies array. Bugreport has been filed about this: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14917