# How can I disallow users from accessing the phpMyAdmin login page?

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to secure phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin)

After searching online someone suggested adding a .htaccess file containing the following

```
Redirect 301 /phpmyadmin http://www.example.com/
```

but this did not work for me. Is the any other way of preventing people from accessing the phpMyAdmin login page by using the url http://www.example.com/phpMyAdmin?

Comment: where did you place the .htaccess file ?

Comment: @Aziz - Website is being hosted with apache on ubuntu. I put the .htaccess in the www folder where the rest of the website files are.

Comment: @stevether - I've tried both with and without capitalization and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the .htaccess redirect is the best way but, you can always go to index.php in the phpMyAdmin folder and insert either

`exit();`

or

`header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com');`

as the first line of index.php. This will just exit or redirect to the main page of your site whenever anyone tries to access that page.

Comment: Well, the redirect as given in the question only makes sense if you don't have phpMyAdmin installed at all (because it prevents _everyone_ from getting to the login page, not only hackers), but in that case there's no point in having a redirect in the first place. In any case, if you are going to use a redirect it's better to put it in the server configuration than in an `.htaccess` file.