# Linux alternatives to Sequel Pro? (GUI based sql navigator)

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, debian

Anyone have any suggestions?  Running Debian and looking for a good alternative.

Comment: Still to this day I've not seen a Mysql client that can touch SequelPro for simplicity and elegance.

Comment: @Ray Try [SQLECTRON](https://sqlectron.github.io/). Design is sleek IMO but not much functionality. I don't really care about that since I need it for basic stuff only.

Comment: I built and maintain https://beekeeperstudio.io, our goal is to become a cross platform gui as nice to use as sequel pro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and find it adequate for most purposes, however I use greasemonkey to enhance various aspects. [Here are a number of such scripts](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=phpmyadmin), you can of course write one on your own.
Another alternative is [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com). This is a Windows-only ® app but runs pretty well using Wine.
Then there is MySQL Workbench which has been mentioned in other posts. I don't find its query capabilities as fluid as phpmyadmin but generating ERD with it and synchronising with the database is pretty slick.

Comment: One problem with phpmyadmin is that it has to be on the server you are connecting to. One of the great things about sequel pro is that you can connect to any databases, over ssh. I am surprised that windows and linux do not have anything close to sequel pro in usability and reliability. Workbench crashes too much to be worth much of anything. I am going to continue searching but I have been looking for the past year and I don't see anything. I would certainly be willing to pay $80+ for a linux version of sequel pro.

Comment: Just to provide some advice I recommend valentina studio. Not as good as sequel pro but decent. http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview

Comment: I am not comfortable installing a tool like phpmyadmin on servers that I don't manage. I don't install phpmyadmin on servers I do manage because it creates the potential for additional security holes. It is possible to run phpmyadmin from your local machine and access remote servers, but that (unlike SequelPro which just needs SSH access) requires allowing remote access to the DB which also creates a potential security hole and is not recommended. If you do use phpmyadmin, make sure to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin

Comment: Actually, it looks like you may be able run phpmyadmin locally and connect to the remote DB via a SSH tunnel as well. However, I have not done this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773731/ssh-tunnel-via-phpmyadmin

Comment: User was asking for a GUI based navigator

Answer (score 60):

There are a few different options that I know of, depending on the platform you are running it on. You could use the following:

- Linux: Dbeaver
- Windows: HeidiSQL
- Mac: SequelPro

Comment: DBeaver works nice. Workbench used to crash and was not even close to DBeaver in usability.

Comment: Dbeaver is great - low footprint, great functionality and does NOT crash when using mariadb.

Comment: Dbeaver is a great option!

Comment: I vote for [DbSchema](https://dbschema.com)

Answer (score 15):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) is a great and cross platform tool. The UI might not look as slick as Sequel Pro but the features it provides are good enough.

Comment: I`ve just tried Workbench, it is actually not even near on usefullness of Sequel Pro, it is very hard to name it as "alternative". Its like command line is also alternative for sure

Comment: Sequel Pro have much better usability than MySQL Workbench.

Comment: **MySQL Workbench** should be rename to **MySQL Crashbench**

Answer (score 2):

Yes! The last version of MySQL Workbench, in linux, is better than Sequel Pro.

With MySQL Workbench you can easily query, export data as csv and other formats, edit table data. It has a query guide inside. You can see the schema list, the table list, the columns for each table, the query box and the query result, everything at the same time.

Comment: Sequel Pro have much better usability than MySQL Workbench.

Comment: this comment shouldn't be '-1', MySQL workbench is probably the best alternative to phpmyadmin for linux. My only issue with workbench is its a heavy program

Answer (score 2):

I recommend TablePlus:
[tableplus.com](https://tableplus.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[vStudio](http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview) on linux or windows. I did have some problems with it crashing on linux but just updated to the latest version and it seems to run ok. It has a nice query editor and allows you to save your servers and projects. It is the best I have found so far.

[Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql) is a paid client. I have only used it once but it fell short of expectations.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is pretty simple and standard. Because it is web based, no installation required.

Comment: If You're going the web-based route, try MyWebSQL: http://mywebsql.net/ I haven't used it much, but it's a worthy alternative to PMA, which sometimes misbehaves (corrupted exports and/or imports if you compress files).

Answer (score 0):

try sqlyog, awesome and the community edition is free.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend phpmyadmin or mysql workbench is best for any kind of DB GUI.

To setup phpmyadmin [click here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04/) for complete guide.

To download mysql workbench you can simple go in ubuntu software and search mysql workbench and install it. You can [click here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) to download complete offline installer for mysql workbench according to your OS. By terminal you have to follow  these steps [click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

im using SQLyog under wine

i think SQLyog have a good feature, not as much as mysql workbench but much faster

the paid version maybe even better