# Whats unsafe about leaving phpmyadmin with a default user/pass

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I start phpmyadmin I see this message:

> Your configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'.

What's so unsafe about this?
 Unless an attacker can somehow fool mysql into thinking that they're sitting in front of my computer, there's no way for them to get on.

Is there some other way for an attacker to log on to mysql if he isn't from the correct host?

I know that in php you can choose which host you want to be from but unless they have access to edit php files on my server/computer I don't see how they can do any harm.

Comment: How about an attacker on the same _shared host_ IP?

Comment: Anyway, you just don't have to install phpMyAdmin into a production server, it's just too dangerous with it's history of security holes. Don't mess with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always safe to put a password even if your `MySQL` does not allow access from other host than `localhost`.

Your `phpMyAdmin` it's accessed by browser and not by IP.

Even if you host your page on your computer, it is still better to put a password. I get my computer and servers scanned for `*phpMyAdmin*`, `*PMA*` every single day.

So yes, it's unsafe.

Comment: So you're saying that phpmyadmin's ip is checked and not the user connecting so it will always be localhost? Also does this mean that if I get rid of phpmyadmin I won't have any worries?

Comment: No, you should always have worries, there are always holes in server/script/etc .. but you should always try to prevent this kind of things. It's best to secure everything. Even if you protect `root` with password you should still protect `phpMyAdmin` with an `.htaccess` password or a protected directory (that can be accessed only from some IP).

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin)'s a starting point for securing your installation.

Comment: Server installs outdated with security issues, scripts with sql injection .. those kind of things.\

Comment: I get tons of logs with different IP's trying to access `PMA` or alternatives ... :)

Answer (score 1):

For development, it may not be an issue but in a production environment you should NEVER EVER use default security settings.

If you can access phpMyAdmin and ultimately MySQL from the internet that means others can as well and you should choose a secure password and make sure your username is not root.

Most hosting providers force you to choose a secure password anyways.